# undefined variable error in PHP while it's defined before

Tags: php, undefined

i have an error in my PHP code , undefined variable error while it's already  defined before 
this is the first error :

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: utilisateurKore in C:\wamp64\www\myFiles\PHP\views\edit.php on line 16

this is the second error :

this the code wehere the error is :

```
<?PHP
include "../entities/utilisateur.php";
include "../core/utilisateurCore.php";

if (isset($_GET['pseudo'])){
    $utilisateurKore = new utilisateurCore();
    $result=$utilisateurKore->recupererUser($_GET['pseudo']);
    foreach($result as $row){
        $pseudo=$row['pseudo'];
        $mail=$row['mail'];
        $motdepasse=$row['motdepasse'];
            }
}
if (isset($_POST['modifier'])){
    $utilisateur1=new utilisateur($_POST['pseudo'],$_POST['mail'],$_POST['motdepasse']);
    $utilisateurKore->modifierUser($utilisateur1,$_POST['pseudo']);
}

?>
```

this is the class of the variable :

```
<?php 
include "../config.php";
class utilisateurCore{

//edition de profil
  function modifierUser($utilisateur,$pseudo){
    $sql="UPDATE membres SET motdepasse=:motdepasse,mail=:mail WHERE pseudo=:pseudo";

    $db = config::getConnexion(); 
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
try{    
        $req=$db->prepare($sql);
    $motdepasse=$utilisateur->getMotdepasse();
        $mail=$utilisateur->getEmail();

   // $datas = array(':cinn'=>$cinn, ':cin'=>$cin, ':nom'=>$nom,':prenom'=>$prenom,':nbH'=>$nb,':tarifH'=>$tarif);
    $req->bindValue(':mail',$mail);
    $req->bindValue(':motdepasse',$motdepasse);    

            $s=$req->execute();

           // header('Location: index.php');
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            echo " Erreur ! ".$e->getMessage();
        }

  }
  function recupererUser($pseudo){
    $sql="SELECT * from employe where pseudo=$pseudo";
    $db = config::getConnexion();
    try{
    $liste=$db->query($sql);
    return $liste;
    }
        catch (Exception $e){
            die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());
        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: the second error : 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function modifierUser() on null in C:\wamp64\www\myFiles\PHP\views\edit.php on line 16

Comment: make you you are have the correct file path in your include statement.

Comment: the first error is solved i have defined an other object with the same class , but there is a second error 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method utilisateurCore::modifierUser() in C:\wamp64\www\myFiles\PHP\views\edit.php on line 17
 
while this method is already defined in utilisateurCore.php

Comment: You need to specify whether it's a public function, private or protected. The way you are using it you'll want it to be public

Comment: @Jase i have called another function from the same class recupererUtilisateur() and it's detected as a defined function .

Answer (score 1):

`$utilisateurKore` is only defined when the first if condition matches (`isset($_GET['pseudo'])`). 
If the first condition does NOT match, but the second does, you will get this error.

you could either move the second condition (`isset($_POST['modifier'])`) into the code block of the first condition or set / initialize `$utilisateurKore` with a default value first.

Comment: the modifierUser() function is still undefined here :



<?PHP
include "../entities/utilisateur.php";
include "../core/utilisateurCore.php";
if (isset($_POST['modifier'])){
    $pseudo=$_POST['pseudo'];
    $mail=$_POST['mail'];
    $motdepasse=$_POST['motdepasse'];
    $utilisateur1=new utilisateur($pseudo,$mail,$motdepasse);
    $utilisateurC=new utilisateurCore();
    $utilisateurC->modifierUser($utilisateur1,$pseudo);
}

?>